# "tns preview" is not working while Migrating an existing Angular project with NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am migrating an existing Angular project with NativeScript but when I hit the command tns preview it is giving two error. One from Angular and another from Java.

The error log is here:

```
src/app/components/widget/toolbar/toolbar.component.ts:2:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/ipc.service'.

2 import { IpcService } from 'src/app/services/ipc.service';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/components/widget/toolbar/toolbar.component.ts:4:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/user-state.service'.

4 import { UserStateService } from 'src/app/services/user-state.service';
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/components/widget/toolbar/toolbar.component.ts:5:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/websocket.service'.

5 import { WebSocketService } from 'src/app/services/websocket.service';
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/components/widget/toolbar/toolbar.component.ts:6:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/authentication.service'.

6 import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/components/widget/transition-tab/transition-tab.component.ts:2:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/common.service'.

2 import { CommonService } from 'src/app/services/common.service';
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/authentication.service.ts:4:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment'.

4 import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/authentication.service.ts:6:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/common.service'.

6 import { CommonService } from 'src/app/services/common.service';
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/cancelStreamPacketStructures.ts:2:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/sotpConstants'.

2 import * as SOTP from 'src/app/services/sotpConstants';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/common.service.ts:3:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/sotpConstants'.

3 import * as SOTP from 'src/app/services/sotpConstants';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/createWindow.service.ts:6:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/authentication.service'.

6 import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/quotePacketStructures.ts:2:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/sotpConstants'.

2 import * as SOTP from 'src/app/services/sotpConstants';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/tradePacketStructures.ts:2:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/sotpConstants'.

2 import * as SOTP from 'src/app/services/sotpConstants';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/websocket.service.ts:7:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/sotpConstants'.

7 import * as SOTP from 'src/app/services/sotpConstants';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/websocket.service.ts:10:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/precision.pipe'.

10 import { PrecisionPipe } from 'src/app/precision.pipe';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Project successfully prepared (android)
Start sending initial files for platform android.
Successfully sent initial files for platform android.
LOG from device Galaxy On8: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
LOG from device Galaxy On8: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
LOG from device Galaxy On8: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.preview/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.

StackTrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.preview/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
        at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1209)
        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1096)
        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1083)
        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1063)
        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1055)
        at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267)
        ... 9 more

LOG from device Galaxy On8: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
LOG from device Galaxy On8: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
```

It shows that the modules are not found but I have checked the modules are correct and running perfectly on the "ng serve" but they are not working on "tns preview".

Comment: idk for sure but you could try relative paths instead of absolute ones

Answer (score 0):

seems like it doesn't find module try path like '../service/serviceComponent' etc
may it resolve this and try tns preview --bundle

Answer (score 0):

Nativescript recommends using remapped imports
(see [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/intro#remapped-imports) )

try  import  '@src/....'

also, make sure that these components and services are inside app.module.tns.ts